# How to solve issue in "schema.registry.url" while connecting elastic search with Kafka Connect?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to connect Kafka Connect with elastic search sink. I am not using in confluent but in standalone mode. This is my elasticsearch connector configuration.

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=mysql-jdbc-mall
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
connection.url=http://172.**.*.**:5601
type.name=kafka-connect
elastic.security.protocol=SSL
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

My connect-standalone.properties is

```
bootstrap.servers=Ni****ing:9092
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

And when I run the connector I get the issue as.

```
[2020-01-21 09:31:03,676] ERROR Failed to start task elasticsearch-sink-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:464)
io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
        at io.confluent.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:243)
        at io.confluent.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:78)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.java:100)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverterConfig.<init>(AvroConverterConfig.java:27)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:58)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:440)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.createConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:311)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.updateConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:336)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:214)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:115)
[2020-01-21 09:31:03,677] INFO Created connector elasticsearch-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:112)
```

**Update**

As I dont have a '/etc/schema-registry' file. I changed my connect-standalone.properties to

```
bootstrap.servers=Nifi-Staging:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

but when I use JSONConverter I get this error.

```
[2020-01-21 16:12:04,939] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:231)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:142)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:133)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-01-21 16:12:04,946] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
[2020-01-21 16:12:04,946] INFO Stopping ElasticsearchSinkTask (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask:190)
```

Comment: What research did you do on that error?

Comment: I initialy had json converter and i changed to avro converter. But i dont schema registry files in /etc . Json converter shows this error

Comment: Is your data produced in JSON or Avro? You cannot just set the converter without knowing that. You can run `sudo find / -iname '*avro*.properties'` to find all relevant config files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter` is *required* to define the `schema.registry.url`

Remove both `schemas.enable` props because they only apply to JSON ; Avro *always has a schema*, then add the URLs instead

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://...
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://...
```

You can find a sample Connect property file under the `etc/schema-registry` folder

If you are not using Avro, change the converter to match your data. The key and value can be completely different types, too

---

In addition, the elasticsearch url should be different; such as something running on port 9200, not kibana on 5601

---

> I am not using in confluent but in standalone mode.

I assume you mean the `confluent` command? That just runs `kafka-connect-distributed` for you, and distributed mode is actually preferred.

Comment: For background on converters, Avro vs JSON, etc see [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)

Comment: I have editted the content as I got new errors. Please check. Thankyou

Comment: @AfzalAbdulAzeez What version of Kafka Connect, the Connector, and 
 Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Kafka Connect Version 2.0, January 2004 , Connector Version :confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.4.0 and Elasticsearch version : 6.4.3

Comment: @AfzalAbdulAzeez Is ES up and running? It typically runs at **9200**. Kibana runs at 5601... The connector is failing here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/blob/v5.4.0/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/elasticsearch/jest/JestElasticsearchClient.java#L231

Comment: I got it when I gave the port No. 9200. Tq :) I can give you the green tick if you post this as the answer

Comment: @AfzalAbdulAzeez Done